# Query is inputting the actual time instead

Tags: php, mysql, time

I want to create a form to ban players in my server, and this is how it looks like my form and my query.

```
<!-- BAN FORM -->
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['ban'])){

    $time=time().'000';
    $durat=$_POST['duration']*86400000;
    $duration=$time+$durat;

    $banuid = "UPDATE userprofile SET bantime=:duration WHERE uid = '$_GET[uid]'";
    $query = $dbh1 -> prepare($banuid);
    $query-> bindParam(':duration',$duration, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query -> execute();

}
?>
<form method="POST">
<div class="col-md-12">

<label for="inputUsername" class="sr-only">Duration</label>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="icon-inputUsername"><i class="flaticon-clock-2"></i> </span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="duration" size="18" placeholder="Type how many days">
</div>

<button name="ban" class="btn btn-lg btn-gradient-warning btn-block btn-rounded mb-4 mt-5" type="submit">BAN</button>

</div>
</form>
```

The problem is when i input the time ( which should be in day's) it will add in database the actual time.

could anyone please give me a hint?

Thank you

Comment: You have a glaring sql injection in your use of uid unsanitized from url parameters

Comment: shall i change it to uid=:uid and bind the parameter?

Comment: yeah, and `bindParam(...)` on `uid`

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few problems in your PHP code.

```
$time=time().'000';  
// → '1595089303000' (string)
$durat=$_POST['duration']*86400000; 
// → $_POST['duration'] is a string, e.g. '3'
// → $durat is implicitly casted to integer, e.g. 259200000 (int)
$duration=$time+$durat;
// → string + number also does an implicit cast to integer, e.g.
// → $duration = '1595089303000' + 259200000 = 1595348503000 (int)


$banuid = "UPDATE userprofile SET bantime=:duration WHERE uid = '$_GET[uid]'";
$query = $dbh1 -> prepare($banuid);
$query-> bindParam(':duration',$duration, PDO::PARAM_STR);
// → I think this is the problem          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

// → SQL will look like that:
// UPDATE userprofile SET bantime='1595348503000' WHERE uid = '100'
//                                ^-------------^
// You see that the bantime is a string that holds a long number. 
// This should be either a number (without quotes) or a formatted datetime string.

$query -> execute();
```

What datatype is the "bantime" field in your SQL table? A datetime, integer, ...? Most likely it's not a varchar and fails to convert the $duration value. As a fallback MySQL will use the default value, which possibly is `CURRENT_TIEMSTAMP` (which means that you have a datetime field)

Here's a suggestion for cleaner code:

```
// 1. Sanitize all POST/GET values. I assume $uid is a numeric user ID:
$uid = (int) $_GET['uid'];

// 2. Keep the date calculation to numeric values:
$days = (int) $_POST['duration'] * 86400;
$ban_until = time() + $days;

// 3. After the calculation convert the numeric timestamp to the desired SQL format:
//    I assume your bantime field is a DATETIME field, i.e. '2020-07-18 18:45:00'
$mysql_date = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $ban_until );

// 4. When preparing your SQL, always bind _ALL_ user-inputs!
$banuid = "UPDATE userprofile SET bantime=:duration WHERE uid=:uid";
$query = $dbh1->prepare( $banuid );
$query->bindParam(':duration', $mysql_date, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$query->bindParam(':uid', $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();

// The resulting SQL would be:
// UPDATE userprofile SET bantime='2020-07-18 18:45:00' WHERE uid=100
```